# Android How to execute flow.map() in viewModel on Dispatchers.Default

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I am developing an Android application, using the MVVM design pattern.

So, I have a repository that exposes a `flow<T>` to a ViewModel. The ViewModel then converts the `flow<T>` to `LiveData<T>` using `asLiveData()` as per the code below.

```
repository.getFlow().map {
    // I will do some long running work here
}.asLiveData()
```

As you can see, I will do some long-running work in `map { }`. So I want to execute the code inside `map { }` in `Dispatchers.Default` thread.

From my research, I can do with `flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)` or `asLiveData(viewmodelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.Default)` as per the code below.

1. map{} with `flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)`

```
repository.getFlow().map {
   // I will do some long running work here
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default).asLiveData()
```

2. map{} with `asLiveData(viewmodelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.Default)`

```
repository.getFlow().map {
   // I will do some long running work here
}.asLiveData(viewmodelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.Default)
```

I'd like to understand better about coroutine context, scope and flowOn(). So my questions are as follows

1-1. Does `asLiveData(viewmodelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.Default)` mean that `asLiveData()` function will execute in a new coroutine with `Dispatchers.Default` in `viewmodelScope`?

1-2. So, then the `map {}` function executes in the new `coroutine` with `Dispatchers.Default` because flow's intermediate operator executes in consumer's coroutine?

2. I also read `flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)` executes the upstream flow in the CoroutineContext defined in `flowOn()` function, which mean that the map{} will execute in `Dispatchers.Default` thread. Is it fine to use flowOn() in viewmodel with `asLiveData()`?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not sure I understand the question, but basically it means that the flow collection will happen on the passed coroutine context (`viewmodelScope` + bg thread) and the value will be propagated to the livedata from the bg thread. But the propagation (an `emit()` call) will always switch to the Main dispatcher.
2. Yes, when you use `flowOn()`, all the upstream operators (your `map`) are run on the defined dispatcher until new `flowOn()` operator appears. And yes, it is ok to use it with combination with `asLiveData()`.

These two options should be equivalent; I would aim for the clarity, which seems to be better covered with the `flowOn()` usage.

Comment: Thank you for your response, one quick question. viewmodelScope + Dispatchers.Default means that it creates a new corouitne in viewmodelScope but it executes in Dispatchers.Default thread, am I correct please?

Comment: Yes, it does create new coroutine as you've described.